# Installed Libreoffice 5 on lubuntu - no menu entries

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice

I've installed LibreOffice 5.0 using the .deb packages archive from [libreoffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/).

There are no menu entries in the LXPanel menu.

So I've created a simlink using

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/libreoffice5.0 ./Desktop/
```

When I double click this link, a dialog box pops up asking me if I want to "Execute", "Execute in Terminal", etc.

How can I make this link work so that it always just runs "Execute"?

Comment: it seems like no `.desktop` file came with the `.deb` file. maybe you will need to make your own file.

Comment: @LittleByBlue Any hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong with your installation, as no `.desktop` file is provided.

A workaround is to make your own `.desktop` file. You can try this:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/applications/libreoffice5.dektop
```

enter:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Libreoffice5
Exec=/usr/local/bin/libreoffice5.0
Categories=Gtk;Utility;Office;
```

see also:
[ubuntu's page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Comment: And then reboot I'm guessing?

Comment: err, no reboot is required. you can now link this file to your desktop.

Comment: Okay, yes I have entried in the "start menu" now

Answer (score 1):

See if you have a folder like `/opt/libreoffice4.4/share/xdg`. You may have `libreoffice5/0`?

I have several libreoffice .desktop files there. If you have them as well, just copy them (using `sudo`) over to /usr/share/applications. Lxpanel should surely see them then without need of a reboot.

Comment: Hmm, i seem to have 2 copies of everything now in my menu...